# Annotating a table with arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, highlighting

I want to recreate the following table on latex

[image]

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
   \hline
  \footnotesize{ $x$ } & 0.900 & 0.990 & 0.999 & 1.000 & 1.001 & 1.010 & 1.100 \\ \hline
  \footnotesize{ $f(x)$} & 1.810 & 1.980 & 1.998 & 2.000 & 2.002 & 2.020 & 2.210 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can draw with TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
% put a row of 8 elements
\newcommand{\putrow}[9]{
\path (0,#1) node{#2}
++(0:1) node{#3} ++(0:1) node{#4}
++(0:1) node{#5} ++(0:1) node{#6} 
++(0:1) node{#7} ++(0:1) node{#8} ++(0:1) node{#9};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.4,yscale=.6]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\fill[cyan!30] (0,0) rectangle +(1,-2);
\draw (0,0) grid (8,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[-stealth,magenta,shorten >=.5pt,
every node/.style={midway,scale=.8}]
\draw[shift={(90:1)}] (1,0)--(4,0)    node[above]{$x$ approaches $1$};
\draw[shift={(90:1)}] (7,0)--(4,0)    node[above]{$x$ approaches $1$};
\draw[shift={(-90:2)}] (1,0)--(4,0)   node[below]{$f(x)$ approaches $2$};
\draw[shift={(-90:2)}] (7,0)--(4,0)   node[below]{$f(x)$ approaches $2$};
\end{scope}

\putrow{0}{$x$}{0.900}{0.990}{0.999}{1.000}{1.001}{1.010}{1.100}
\putrow{-1}{$f(x)$}{1.810}{1.980}{1.998}{2.000}{2.002}{2.020}{2.210}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**PS** (July 2020) I add a `matrix` version of the figure, somewhat similar to Zarko's code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
nodes={draw,minimum height=4ex,minimum width=3.3em,anchor=center},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column 1/.style ={nodes={fill=orange!30}}
]{
x   & 0.900 & 0.990 & 0.999 & 1.000 & 1.001 & 1.010 & 1.100 \\ 
f(x)& 1.810 & 1.980 & 1.998 & 2.000 & 2.002 & 2.020 & 2.210 \\
};

\def\d{.6}
\begin{scope}[-stealth,orange,shorten >=.5pt,
every node/.style={midway,scale=.8}]
\draw ([shift={(90:\d)}]m-1-2.center)--([shift={(90:\d)}]m-1-5.center)    
node[above]{$x$ approaches $1$};
\draw ([shift={(90:\d)}]m-1-8.center)--([shift={(90:\d)}]m-1-5.center)    
node[above]{$x$ approaches $1$};
\draw ([shift={(-90:\d)}]m-2-2.center)--([shift={(-90:\d)}]m-2-5.center)   
node[below]{$f(x)$ approaches $2$};
\draw ([shift={(-90:\d)}]m-2-8.center)--([shift={(-90:\d)}]m-2-5.center)   
node[below]{$f(x)$ approaches $2$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just added a `matrix` version, similar to Zarko's code below!

Comment: It is perfect....just your answer was upvoted by me.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Also with `tikz`, but now with use of the `matrix` library. For arrows, edge labels are employed `arrows.meta` and `quoted` libraries:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix,
                quotes
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw, purple, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}, semithick}, shorten >=1pt,
every edge quoetes/.style = {font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes = {draw, minimum height=4ex, minimum width=3.3em, 
                      inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             column 1/.append style = {nodes={fill=cyan!30}}
            ]
{
 x   & 0.900 & 0.990 & 0.999 & 1.000 & 1.001 & 1.010 & 1.100    \\ 
f(x) & 1.810 & 1.980 & 1.998 & 2.000 & 2.002 & 2.020 & 2.210    \\
};
\draw   (m-1-2.north |- m.north) edge["$x$ approaches $1$"] (m-1-5.north |- m.north)
        (m-1-8.north |- m.north) edge["$f(x)$ approaches $1$" '] (m-1-5.north |- m.north)
        (m-1-2.south |- m.south) edge["$x$ approaches $2$" '] (m-1-5.north |- m.south)
        (m-1-8.south |- m.south) edge["$f(x)$ approaches $2$"] (m-1-5.north |- m.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wrote **two macros** (`\valeur` and `\fromto`) that **automatically** place the arrow **above** the path and the text **above** the arrow or **below** depending on whether the path goes from **left to right** or not.

Its advantage is that it allows you to add arrows to any array written with a specialized package such as `array`, `tabular` or any other package designed to write arrays. This avoids having to rewrite the code of an already created table.

#### For example:

The arrow is always positioned on the ***left side*** in the direction of the built path. That is to say: above when the path goes from ***left to right*** and below otherwise. The text is automatically positioned above or below the arrow.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\valeur}[2]{
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center](#1){#2};}
\newcommand{\fromto}[4][]{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,auto=left,>={Stealth[length=5pt, inset=1pt,sep]}]
    \path[draw,thick,#1]($(#2.center)!5mm!90:(#3.center)$)--($(#3.center)!5mm!-90:(#2.center)$)node[midway]{#4};}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
 \node[] (A)at(0,0){A};
 \node[] (B) at (8,0){B};
 \draw[densely dotted](A)--(B)node[midway,fill=white]{path from A to B};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
\fromto[align=center,dashed,->,blue] {A}{B}{from A to B:\\ the arrow is \textbf{above} the path A--B \\ the text is \textbf{above} the arrow}
\fromto[align=center,dashed,->,red] {B}{A}{from B to A:\\ line arrow is \textbf{below} the path A--B,\\ the text is \textbf{below} the arrow}

\end{document}
```

#### Code and result (to be compile twice):

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{myviolet}{RGB}{243,29,143}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\valeur}[2]{
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center](#1){#2};}
\newcommand{\fromto}[4][]{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,auto=left,>={Stealth[length=5pt, inset=1pt,sep]}]
    \path[draw=myviolet,thick,#1]
    ($(#2.center)!5mm!90:(#3.center)$)--($(#3.center)!5mm!-90:(#2.center)$)node[midway,myviolet,font=\bf]{#4};}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
   \hline
  \footnotesize{ $x$ } & \valeur{a1}{0.900} & 0.990 & 0.999 & \valeur{b1}{1.000} & 1.001 & 1.010 & \valeur{c1}{1.100} \\ \hline
  \footnotesize{ $f(x)$} & \valeur{a2}{1.810} & 1.980 & 1.998 & \valeur{b2}{2.000} & 2.002 & 2.020 & \valeur{c2}{2.210} \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 
\fromto[->] {a1}{b1}{$x$ approaches 1.}
\fromto[<-] {b1}{c1}{$x$ approaches 1.}
\fromto[<-] {b2}{a2}{$f(x)$ approaches 2.}
\fromto[->] {c2}{b2}{$f(x)$ approaches 2.}

\end{document}
```

#### The first macro called `valeur`:

marks the beginning and the end of the arrow with a TikZ `node` and displays the value contained in the table cell.

```
\newcommand{\valeur}[2]{
        \tikz[remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center](#1){#2};}
```

It has two arguments:

- the first `#1` is the **name** we give to the `node`
- the second `#2` is the **value** of this `node`.

#### The second macro called `\fromto`:

This macro always positions the arrow on the left side in the direction of the path. Above when the path goes from ***left to right*** and below otherwise.
This macro has 4 arguments:

- the first one `#1` is optional and allows to transmit TikZ options to the path **< options>**
- the second `#2` is the starting point **< from>**
- the third `#3` is the arrival point **< to>**
- the fourth `#4` is the text to be positioned **< text>**

```
\newcommand{\fromto}[4][]{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,auto=left,>={Stealth[length=5pt, inset=1pt,sep]}]
    \path[draw=myviolet,thick,#1]
    ($(#2.center)!5mm!90:(#3.center)$)--($(#3.center)!5mm!-90:(#2.center)$)node[midway,myviolet,font=\bf]{#4};}
```

---

## How does it work?

The principle is the following: if the path goes **from left to right**, the arrow and the text are placed **above** the path, **otherwise** it is placed **below**.
This is done **without** any positioning tests, but using the **properties of the rotations**
This avoids using 2 options that are de facto useless:

- one for the placement of the arrows (up or down)
- as well as one option for the placement of the text relative to these arrows (above or below).

#### Rotations

In geometry, a positive angle is an anti-clockwise rotation. A negative angle is a clockwise rotation.

[image: angles]

#### From LEFT to RIGHT

When the path goes from left to right (i.e. from point A to point B), the points located 5mm from each other are rotated as shown in this figure. This builds a new path 5 mm higher.

[image: higher path]

#### From RIGHT to LEFT

When the path goes from right to left (i.e. from point B to point A), the same is done as shown in this figure. This builds a new path 5 mm lower.
[image: lower path]

> In each case, the **first** rotation is **positive** and the **second negative**. These rotations are performed with the `calc` library.
> To place the text, I use the `auto=left` option which allows me to always place the text on the same side of a path.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a slight variation on Black Mild's solution. Instead of using a Tikz matrix of nodes, I construct the array with `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. A PDF/Tikz node is constructed under each cell of the array and I draw the arrows as Black Mild does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines,code-before = \columncolor{orange!30}{1}]
x   & 0.900 & 0.990 & 0.999 & 1.000 & 1.001 & 1.010 & 1.100 \\ 
f(x)& 1.810 & 1.980 & 1.998 & 2.000 & 2.002 & 2.020 & 2.210 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}[-stealth,orange,shorten >=.5pt,
                      every node/.style={midway,scale=.8}]
  \def\d{.6}
  \draw ([shift={(90:\d)}]1-2.center)--([shift={(90:\d)}]1-5.center)    
  node[above]{$x$ approaches $1$};
  \draw ([shift={(90:\d)}]1-8.center)--([shift={(90:\d)}]1-5.center)    
  node[above]{$x$ approaches $1$};
  \draw ([shift={(-90:\d)}]2-2.center)--([shift={(-90:\d)}]2-5.center)   
  node[below]{$f(x)$ approaches $2$};
  \draw ([shift={(-90:\d)}]2-8.center)--([shift={(-90:\d)}]2-5.center)   
  node[below]{$f(x)$ approaches $2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]